# Background color showing more than two shades? [Help!?]

Tags: html, css

I have a very confusing issue with this line:

`<body style="background-color:#100F0F;">`

Simple, right? But, for some reason, I get this:

[image]

This happens with other colours too.

Here is the code for a very basic page:

```
<html>
<body style='font-family:Helvetica;color:white;background-color:#100F0F;padding-top:50px;'>

<h1>Hello!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the weird (buggy?) result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdapH.png

I've never had this issue before- it just happened one day when I logged in, nothing changed.

*Has anyone seen/had this (very confusing) issue before?*

Comment: Can you post the code for that page?

Comment: I am having this issue in chrome lately

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have done this

Comment: @eggman What version of chrome are you using? I copied your code and it looks fine on my chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Your containers background is #100F0F; meanwhile the elements contained inside of it have a different background color. You need to make sure that everything inside that container has a background color of #100F0F;

Comment: Look at the basic page I just made though, there is only one element and yet the issue still occurs?

Answer (score 0):

is very weird, I tried in firefox, safari and chrome with your code and I couldnt reproduce the error...

```css
body {
font-family:Helvetica;
color:white;
background-color:#100F0F;
padding-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
/*your css for the body would be here
or in an external .css file*/
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Hello!</h1>
<div>Seems to work fine</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Take a look att the demo and tell me if you see a different shade. In that case it could be you chrome version.